# Convert linestring to polygon of geojson file in Geopandas

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas, cad, dxf

I have the following CAD file in `dxf` format which display in `autocad` looking like:
[image]

I convert it to `geojson` format file named `test.geojson` with GDAL org2org but all in `type: LineString`

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "entities",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Layer": "0" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 30.0, 0.0 ], [ 30.0, 9.0 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Layer": "0" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 16.0, 47.0 ], [ 16.0, 34.0 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Layer": "0" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 16.0, 13.0 ], [ 16.0, 0.0 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Layer": "0" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 0.0, 31.0 ], [ 9.0, 31.0 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Layer": "0" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 30.0, 31.0 ], [ 39.0, 31.0 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Layer": "0" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 0.0, 23.0 ], [ 9.0, 23.0 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Layer": "0" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 30.0, 23.0 ], [ 39.0, 23.0 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Layer": "0" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 0.0, 16.0 ], [ 9.0, 16.0 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Layer": "0" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 30.0, 16.0 ], [ 39.0, 16.0 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Layer": "0" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 0.0, 0.0 ], [ 39.0, 0.0 ], [ 39.0, 47.0 ], [ 0.0, 47.0 ], [ 0.0, 0.0 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Layer": "0" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 9.0, 38.0 ], [ 11.0, 38.0 ], [ 11.0, 34.0 ], [ 28.0, 34.0 ], [ 28.0, 38.0 ], [ 30.0, 38.0 ], [ 30.0, 9.0 ], [ 28.0, 9.0 ], [ 28.0, 13.0 ], [ 11.0, 13.0 ], [ 11.0, 9.0 ], [ 9.0, 9.0 ], [ 9.0, 38.0 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Layer": "0" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 11.0, 32.0 ], [ 17.0, 32.0 ], [ 17.0, 15.0 ], [ 11.0, 15.0 ], [ 11.0, 32.0 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Layer": "0" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 20.0, 32.0 ], [ 28.0, 32.0 ], [ 28.0, 15.0 ], [ 20.0, 15.0 ], [ 20.0, 32.0 ] ] } }
]
}
```

I want to convert it to `type: polygon` with display as follow image showing:
[image]

How can I do that in Geopandas? Thanks.

BTW, I read `test.geojson` file, it looks like:

```
import geopandas as gpd
df = gpd.read_file("test.geojson")
df.head(5)
```

Output:

```
  Layer               SubClasses EntityHandle                                           geometry
0     0  AcDbEntity:AcDbPolyline          106  LINESTRING (30.35270412013777 0.79246615687498...
1     0  AcDbEntity:AcDbPolyline          107  LINESTRING (16.16520412013776 47.1049661568749...
2     0  AcDbEntity:AcDbPolyline          108  LINESTRING (16.16520412013776 13.4799661568749...
3     0  AcDbEntity:AcDbPolyline          109  LINESTRING (0.665204120137787 31.2924661568749...
4     0  AcDbEntity:AcDbPolyline          10A  LINESTRING (30.35270412013777 31.2924661568749...
```

Comment: You have 9 two-point lines, and 5 poly-lines. You ask us to create 12 polygons from them. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, I think maybe the problem comes from fact that every looks like polygon in first image is not actually closed. So after convert it from `dxf` to `geojson`, it's `LineString` instead of `Polygon`.

Comment: I want to get the `edge points` or `corner points` for each polygon from 1 to 12 in order to display them in JavaScript, but I don't know how to group them correctly.